# TypeError occurs when instantiating an instance of my extended Ext JS FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, formpanel

I have the following FormPanel in my javascript

```
EditRequestForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    labelWidth: 75,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    defaults: { width: 230 },

    items: [{
        name: 'id',
        hidden: true
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        name: 'name',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Test Plan File',
        name: 'testplan'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Scheduled Time',
        name: 'scheduledtime'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save'
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});
```

When I try to create an instance of this with the following code:

```
        var form = new EditRequestForm({
            header: false
        });
```

The following exception occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'add'
```

I can't see anything that is wrong.  If I take out the `header: false` call, the same thing happens, so that's not it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best fix, but it removed the js error for me.

```
EditRequestForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
        labelWidth: 75,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: {
            width: 230
        },
        initComponent: function () {
            Ext.apply(this, {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                items: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    name: 'name',
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Test Plan File',
                    name: 'testplan'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Scheduled Time',
                    name: 'scheduledtime'
                }],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Save'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Cancel'
                }]
            });
            EditRequestForm.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: This is mostly correct... you will need to assign the new xtype though.

@KallDrexx - notice how the configuration of the object is contained in the initComponent section.  Please refer to the ExtJS Tutorials at this URL: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Component:Extending_Ext_Components

Comment: This seems like the best answer. BUT, **you should never put an object in the prototype, so defaults needs to move into initComponent too**.  http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext-part-3/#adding-objects-to-prototype PS. If you override constructor instead (do the apply after the superclass) then your config will appear in initialConfig if you should needed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not extending the component properly.  Your code is missing two major pieces:

1. initComponent : {}  //this is where your items should go for "default" configs
2. Register the xtype
   `Ext.reg("myRequestForm","EditRequestForm");`

Please refer to the ExtJS tutorial for extending components at [this link](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual%3aComponent%3aExtending_Ext_Components)

Answer (score 0):

The data you are passing to Ext.extend should be passed to the form constructor.  It appears you are not trying creating a new class with the data you pass to Ext.extend; rather it appears you are trying to instantiate a form object.  Try this:

```
EditRequestForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 75,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: { width: 230 },

        items: [{
            name: 'id',
            hidden: true
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Test Plan File',
            name: 'testplan'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Scheduled Time',
            name: 'scheduledtime'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
        }, {
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Why can't I extend it though?  I don't want the form instantiated until I am ready to use it, and I would prefer it not to exist between instantiations.  I could wrap it into a function to return it, but extending it seems like it should be the proper way to do this.

Comment: You may extend it.  But, you don't overwrite items - when you overwrite items in your class the constructor is unhappy.  Many people overwrite parameters and methods using Ext.extend, but items should not be overwritten.

Comment: Why are you extending?  Do you want to create many EditRequestForms?  If no, then I suggest you might simply instantiate.

Comment: I will only have one active at once, so technically this is fine.  I am more interested in why my extension is not working though, because I have other uses for FormPanel in which I will need multiple instances of the same form.

Comment: OK.  Remove items from the above code and pass it to the constructor.  IMHO, all five parameters should be passed to the constructor, but items is your biggest problem now.